# fish - How to list all subdirectories and files when using tab completion

Tags: fish

How do I list all traversable sub directories and files that come up when using tab and `cd`ing or using some other completion to a path or file in the fish shell?

Comment: The behavior you want is a really, and I do mean extremely, bad idea. At a bare minimum the expansion should halt after a reasonable depth. Do you really want an interactive feature to take an unbounded amount of time to produce results if the directory tree you happen to be in has a pathological number of subdirectories?

Comment: No I mean single level deep.  This works for other completions like poetry for python so I don't know why not cd.